# LinkedIn API to get 1st degree connections and company name, positions and industry?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am using this code to access the LinkedIn API and it's working perfectly, but it only gets details like first name, last-name, headline, and email.

I want to get the user's connections, company name, company type, company size, positions, and industry.

How can I get these details through the **LinkedIn** API ?

```
<?php
// Change these
define('API_KEY',      [api_key]);
define('API_SECRET',   [api_secret]);
define('REDIRECT_URI', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
define('SCOPE',        'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress rw_nus r_network');

// You'll probably use a database
session_name('linkedin');
session_start();

// OAuth 2 Control Flow
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    // LinkedIn returned an error
    print $_GET['error'] . ': ' . $_GET['error_description'];
    exit;
} elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // User authorized your application
    if ($_SESSION['state'] == $_GET['state']) {
        // Get token so you can make API calls
        getAccessToken();
    } else {
        // CSRF attack? Or did you mix up your states?
        exit;
    }
} else { 
    if ((empty($_SESSION['expires_at'])) || (time() > $_SESSION['expires_at'])) {
        // Token has expired, clear the state
        $_SESSION = array();
    }
    if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        // Start authorization process
        getAuthorizationCode();
    }
}
$user = fetch('GET', 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=12345/connections');
print_r($user);
$name = $user->firstName.' '.$user->lastName;
$email = $user->emailAddress;
$occupation = $user->headline;
exit;

function getAuthorizationCode() {
    $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
                    'client_id' => API_KEY,
                    'scope' => SCOPE,
                    'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
                    'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
              );

    // Authentication request
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

    // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
    $_SESSION['state'] = $params['state'];

    // Redirect user to authenticate
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}

function getAccessToken() {
    $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                    'client_id' => API_KEY,
                    'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
                    'code' => $_GET['code'],
                    'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
              );

    // Access Token request
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);

    // Tell streams to make a POST request
    $context = stream_context_create(
                    array('http' => 
                        array('method' => 'POST',
                        )
                    )
                );

    // Retrieve access token information
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Native PHP object, please
    $token = json_decode($response);

    // Store access token and expiration time
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this! 
    $_SESSION['expires_in']   = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
    $_SESSION['expires_at']   = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time

    return true;
}

function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
    $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
                    'format' => 'json',
              );

    // Need to use HTTPS
    //$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    $url = $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
    $context = stream_context_create(
                    array('http' => 
                        array('method' => $method,
                        )
                    )
                );
    // Hocus Pocus
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    // Native PHP object, please
    return json_decode($response);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1st degree connections, you may only retrieve basic profile fields and you can use like this. for reference http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

```
$user = fetch('GET', 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:
    (id,first-name,last-name,location:(name),picture-url)');
```

Comment: What is "12345" in id=12345 ??
And i want current user's company info and current user's 1st degree connection. I try this code its generate error

Comment: for current user connection you can use http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:
    (id,first-name,last-name,location:(name),picture-url and for user profile you can use http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/profile:
    (id,first-name,last-name,location:(name),picture-url and for user